# PHP How to access SimpleXMLElement object variable outside foreach

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

If I have a SimpleXMLElement object that is inside a foreach loop, How do I access it outside the loop?

```
$auth_tokens = array('tok1', 'tok2', 'tok3', 'tok4');

foreach($auth_tokens as $auth_token) { // 4 iterations in loop
    $response = curl_exec($connection); // API xml response
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); // loaded xml into object
}

echo header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

`.=` does not work

`[]` does not work

**Update:**

below is what's actually being output from the api xml `$response`. As you can see, because I'm querying 4 auth tokens, on each iteration it's a new xml response. When I try to access it outside the loop, it's not working due to multiple `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` xml headers.

I'm stuck. Not sure how to put all 4 responses into one.

**Update 2:**

Nick helped me figure out how to put all 4 responses into one xml doc, but I need to edit node names and values and that was easy to do when the xml is in a SimpleXMLElement object. So I thought I could manipulate the data first while it is in the object, then when I'm done, convert the object back to xml and save. But I was running into problems when accessing the object outside the loop. It's because there are 4 objects and not just 1, so `.=` was not saving the data.

This is what the API outputs when I `echo $response;` and view source. It's just pure xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:04:38.375Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>11306025</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T14:38:44.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:04:39.049Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>3</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>39168452</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T14:38:53.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>37219192</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>37198277</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:35:01.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:04:39.454Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>2</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>16283499</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>16283499</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:40.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:04:39.782Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>26348797</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

This is what I get when I do a `var_dump ($response);` and view source.

```
string(504) "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:10:49.358Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>11306025</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T14:38:44.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
"
string(797) "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:10:49.439Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>3</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>39168452</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T14:38:53.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>37219192</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>37198277</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:35:01.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
"
string(798) "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:10:50.001Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>3</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>16283499</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>16283499</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:40.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>16275107</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T16:09:40.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
"
string(504) "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:10:50.329Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Success</Ack>
  <Version>1083</Version>
  <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
  <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
  </PaginationResult>
  <OrderArray>
    <Order>
      <OrderID>26348797</OrderID>
      <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
      <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z</CreatedTime>
    </Order>
  </OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
"
```

If i use `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);` in the foreach, and `var_dump ($xml);`, 4 objects gets output.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (6) {
  ["Timestamp"]=>
  string(24) "2018-10-26T16:32:21.048Z"
  ["Ack"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["Version"]=>
  string(4) "1083"
  ["Build"]=>
  string(28) "E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1"
  ["PaginationResult"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["TotalNumberOfEntries"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["OrderArray"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["Order"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
      ["OrderID"]=>
      string(26) "11306025"
      ["OrderStatus"]=>
      string(9) "Completed"
      ["CreatedTime"]=>
      string(24) "2018-10-26T14:38:44.000Z"
    }
  }
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (6) {
  ["Timestamp"]=>
  string(24) "2018-10-26T16:32:21.736Z"
  ["Ack"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["Version"]=>
  string(4) "1083"
  ["Build"]=>
  string(28) "E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1"
  ["PaginationResult"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
    ["TotalNumberOfEntries"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  ["OrderArray"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["Order"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(25) "39168452"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T14:38:53.000Z"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(26) "37219192"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(26) "37198277"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T15:35:01.000Z"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(26) "37185515"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T16:24:19.000Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (6) {
  ["Timestamp"]=>
  string(24) "2018-10-26T16:32:22.529Z"
  ["Ack"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["Version"]=>
  string(4) "1083"
  ["Build"]=>
  string(28) "E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1"
  ["PaginationResult"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["TotalNumberOfEntries"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["OrderArray"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
    ["Order"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(26) "16283499"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(26) "16283499"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T15:36:40.000Z"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
        ["OrderID"]=>
        string(26) "16275107"
        ["OrderStatus"]=>
        string(9) "Completed"
        ["CreatedTime"]=>
        string(24) "2018-10-26T16:09:40.000Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (6) {
  ["Timestamp"]=>
  string(24) "2018-10-26T16:32:22.751Z"
  ["Ack"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["Version"]=>
  string(4) "1083"
  ["Build"]=>
  string(28) "E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1"
  ["PaginationResult"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["TotalNumberOfEntries"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["OrderArray"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["Order"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
      ["OrderID"]=>
      string(26) "26348797"
      ["OrderStatus"]=>
      string(9) "Completed"
      ["CreatedTime"]=>
      string(24) "2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what gets output when I `echo '<pre>' . var_export($xml, true) . '</pre><br>';`. I find this one is easier to read and can see clear it's 4 objects.

```
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   'Timestamp' => '2018-10-26T16:36:41.377Z',
   'Ack' => 'Success',
   'Version' => '1083',
   'Build' => 'E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1',
   'PaginationResult' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'TotalNumberOfEntries' => '1',
  )),
   'OrderArray' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'Order' => 
    SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
       'OrderID' => '11306025',
       'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
       'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T14:38:44.000Z',
    )),
  )),
))


SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   'Timestamp' => '2018-10-26T16:36:43.083Z',
   'Ack' => 'Success',
   'Version' => '1083',
   'Build' => 'E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1',
   'PaginationResult' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'TotalNumberOfEntries' => '4',
  )),
   'OrderArray' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'Order' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '39168452',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T14:38:53.000Z',
      )),
      1 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '37219192',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z',
      )),
      2 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '37198277',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T15:35:01.000Z',
      )),
      3 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '37185515',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T16:24:19.000Z',
      )),
    ),
  )),
))


SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   'Timestamp' => '2018-10-26T16:36:43.783Z',
   'Ack' => 'Success',
   'Version' => '1083',
   'Build' => 'E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1',
   'PaginationResult' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'TotalNumberOfEntries' => '4',
  )),
   'OrderArray' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'Order' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '16283499',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z',
      )),
      1 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '16283499',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T15:36:40.000Z',
      )),
      2 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '16275107',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T16:09:40.000Z',
      )),
      3 => 
      SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
         'OrderID' => '16258277',
         'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
         'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T16:36:19.000Z',
      )),
    ),
  )),
))


SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   'Timestamp' => '2018-10-26T16:36:44.157Z',
   'Ack' => 'Success',
   'Version' => '1083',
   'Build' => 'E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1',
   'PaginationResult' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'TotalNumberOfEntries' => '1',
  )),
   'OrderArray' => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     'Order' => 
    SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
       'OrderID' => '26348797',
       'OrderStatus' => 'Completed',
       'CreatedTime' => '2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z',
    )),
  )),
))
```

And this is what gets output when I use this `echo header('content-type: text/xml'); echo $xml->asXML();` inside the loop.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:42:57.532Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1083</Version>
    <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
    <PaginationResult>
      <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
    </PaginationResult>
    <OrderArray>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>11306025</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T14:38:44.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
    </OrderArray>
  </GetOrdersResponse>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:42:58.218Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1083</Version>
    <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
    <PaginationResult>
      <TotalNumberOfEntries>4</TotalNumberOfEntries>
    </PaginationResult>
    <OrderArray>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>39168452</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T14:38:53.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>37219192</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>37198277</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:35:01.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>37185515</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T16:24:19.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
    </OrderArray>
  </GetOrdersResponse>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:42:58.861Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1083</Version>
    <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
    <PaginationResult>
      <TotalNumberOfEntries>4</TotalNumberOfEntries>
    </PaginationResult>
    <OrderArray>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>16283499</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>16283499</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:40.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>16275107</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T16:09:40.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>16258277</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T16:36:19.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
    </OrderArray>
  </GetOrdersResponse>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-10-26T16:42:59.253Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1083</Version>
    <Build>E1083_CORE_APIXO_18856776_R1</Build>
    <PaginationResult>
      <TotalNumberOfEntries>1</TotalNumberOfEntries>
    </PaginationResult>
    <OrderArray>
      <Order>
        <OrderID>26348797</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
        <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z</CreatedTime>
      </Order>
    </OrderArray>
  </GetOrdersResponse>
```

What I need is to change all the `<OrderID></OrderID>` nodes to display `<Test></Test>` and append to the value in it, and I did that with this

```
foreach($auth_tokens as $key => $auth_token) {

    $responses = curl_exec($connection);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($responses);
    curl_close($connection);

    $entries = $xml->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfEntries;
    $xml = $xml->OrderArray->Order;

    if($entries == 0) {
        continue;
    } else {

        foreach($xml as $key => $val) {

            $val->Test = substr($val->OrderStatus, 0, 3) . $val->OrderID; // changes the <OrderID> node from <OrderID> to <Test> and appends the first 3 charachters from <OrderStatus> value to the <Test> value
            unset($val->OrderID); // deletes the now empty <OrderID> node

        } // end foreach

    }

echo header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();

} // end foreach
```

And this outputs exactly what I need, except it just needs a parent node wrapped around it and it's only outputting 1 order from each response.

```
<Order>
  <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
  <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
  <Test>Com372191926</Test>
</Order>
<Order>
  <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
  <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z</CreatedTime>
  <Test>Com16283499</Test>
</Order>
<Order>
  <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
  <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z</CreatedTime>
  <Test>Com26348797</Test>
</Order>
```

But I can't seem to get a parent node around this because I can't successfully save this data and access it outside the foreach loop. I'm so close!

Comment: You are overwriting `$xml` each time round the loop. So outside the loop you will see only the last response in `$xml`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I know that. But `.=` is not working to access it outside the loop.

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016076/3950902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I needed to concatenate `.=` inside the child foreach loop, not the parent. Then I was able to access the data outside the loop. And I had to save the data to a variable using `$val->asXML()`. Notice the comment lines in the code below.

```
foreach($auth_tokens as $key => $auth_token) { // 4 iterations in loop

    $responses = curl_exec($connection); // API xml response
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($responses); // loaded xml into SimpleXMLElement object
    curl_close($connection);

    $entries = $xml->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfEntries;
    $xml = $xml->OrderArray->Order; // Just get the Order elements

    if($entries == 0) {
        continue;
    } else {

        foreach($xml as $key => $val) {

            $val->Test = substr($val->OrderStatus, 0, 3) . $val->OrderID; // changes the <OrderID> node from <OrderID> to <Test> and appends the first 3 charachters from <OrderStatus> value to the <Test> value
            unset($val->OrderID); // deletes the <OrderID> node

            $orders .= $val->asXML(); // concatenate here in child loop instead of parent foreach

        } // end child foreach

    }

} // end parent foreach

$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->loadXML('<Orders>' . $orders . '</Orders>'); // able to add my parent node <orders></Orders>
$xml->save('test.xml', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG); // saves xml to file

header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->saveXML(); // saves xml for display
```

The output is exactly what I need, and without too much overhead and it's formatted nicely too.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com10789</Test>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com10790</Test>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com141570</Test>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com141571</Test>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:13:21.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com141572</Test>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:36:41.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com19992</Test>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    <CreatedTime>2018-10-26T15:40:25.000Z</CreatedTime>
    <Test>Com19993</Test>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, aggregating the responses into an XML string and then wrapping that in a root element before converting:

```
$auth_tokens = array('tok1', 'tok2', 'tok3', 'tok4');
$xmlstr = '';
foreach($auth_tokens as $auth_token) { // 4 iterations in loop
    $response = curl_exec($connection); // API xml response
    $xmlstr .= $response;               // add response to XML
}
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<Orders>$xmlstr</Orders>");
header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

**Update**

The above code doesn't work if the XML response includes `<?xml ... >` headers. The quick and dirty fix is to strip them out using `preg_replace` i.e. change `$xmlstr .= $response;` to

```
$xmlstr .= preg_replace('/<\?xml[^>]*>/', '', $response);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/gEsZl)

The "correct" fix is to process the XML responses separately and add them as children to a root document. This can be done using `DomDocument`:

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$xml->loadXML('<Orders></Orders>');
$xmlroot = $xml->documentElement;
$respdoc = new DomDocument();
foreach($auth_tokens as $auth_token) {   // 4 iterations in loop
    $response = curl_exec($connection); // API xml response
    $respdoc->loadXML($response);        // create a domDocument
    $resproot = $respdoc->documentElement;   // get the root element
    $resproot = $xml->importNode($resproot, true); // import into XML
    $xmlroot->appendChild($resproot);
}
header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nIule)

Comment: `.=` is not working, have you tested it? Nothing is output. Only when I move those last 3 lines of code inside the loop, then it outputs.

Comment: @Mike I couldn't test it exactly as you are using it I don't have access to the API you are calling but when I simulated the responses with an array this code worked fine: https://3v4l.org/r7180.

Comment: @Mike can you do a `var_dump` of `$response` inside the loop? That could help debug the problem.

Comment: I updated my question. I added the exact output format I'm getting from the api response. Since it is an xml response, and I'm querying 4 auth tokens in the loop, I get 4 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the response. I think this is the problem.

Comment: @Mike you're right, the extra xml header lines are the issue. Give me a minute and I'll work out a fix

Comment: Hi @Mike, see my edit. I think one of the updates will solve your problem.

Comment: ya I just came up with the str_replace `if ($key !== 0) { $sxml = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '', $sxml); } echo sxml;` but because their is no parent root wrapping around the 4 responses, it still did not work. I'll try your second approach.

Comment: Second approach works, but I wanted to manipulate the xml in object form by using `simplexml_load_string` that way I can do other stuff on it before outputting to a final xml.

Comment: @Mike if you use the first approach I suggested and strip all the xml headers, just replacing the one line in my original answer (which adds a root node around all the responses) that should work (see the first demo link). In terms of the second method, you could just use `$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml->saveXML());` to convert to a SimpleXML value at the end.

Comment: Yes I'll stick to your first approach due to having to do other stuff to the data before finally saving it to xml file. Thanks Nick.

Comment: but instead of using `preg_replace`, I can also use `str_replace` right? `$sxml .= str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '', $sxml);`

Comment: Sure. I just used `preg_replace` as it will keep working if the format of the xml header changes slightly e.g. the version or encoding changes.

Comment: Right I was thinking the same thing. I'll stick to preg_replace for this case then.

Comment: I'm going to post another question. I'm still stuck on same issue but with the object built and figuring out how to combine the 4 objects into one.

Comment: this is the new question that deals with my original issue that I did not fully explain in this first question. Need to combine 4 objects into 1., feel free to check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001447

Comment: Check out https://3v4l.org/t3lP6 is that along the lines of what you were looking for? I know it goes back to DOM but most of these things are a lot easier to do in that than in SimpleXML...

Comment: not sure if that will work because I need it in the object in order to do other stuff to the data. I did not mention that in the question. If I do it this way, then I have to put the dom document back into an object in order to do my other stuff. Just seems like back and forth, back and forth when I should be able to do it in one go.

Comment: What do you need to do? You almost certainly do it in DOM, it is a lot more powerful than SImpleXML...

Comment: @Mike Can you please update either this question or your other one with the exact xml that you get back from the API and exactly what you want as output it's really hard to figure out how to implement it otherwise.

Comment: Nick, I figured it out. I added more details in my question. But now I created an answer too. I'll take any advice you still have on it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016076/3950902

Comment: @Mike your answer looks pretty simple. You should accept it instead of mine.